# Web API 2 - how to recreate the environment an app start

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-migrations

I am pushing my web api project to AWS with elastic beanstalk publish. I want to use this for a demo environment.

Currently, I have it setup to do it in two separate deploys:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base(Helpers.GetRDSConnectionString(), throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        // THIS DEPLOY IS USED TO DELETE THE CURRENT DATABASE
        //SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        //Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new 
        DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());

        // THIS DEPLOY IS USED TO SEED THE DATABASE
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new 
        MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
     }
```

However, the database tries to seed itself whenever the app pool wakes up again. Is this somewhere in app.start where I can put this logic so that it only tried to recreate the database when the app is initially deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `Application_Start` which is called only one time during the life cycle of an application.

**example**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<SomeContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());
}
```

[DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)